# SQL Server Excel Linked Server Remote Server Execution Issues

Tags: sql-server, excel, linked-server

This is the first time I've had to work with an Excel sheet as a linked server, and after a whole ton of struggling with it and solving one issue only to hit another I've decided to reach out. Long story short I have a SP that pulls data from an Excel linked server(this was originally just an open datasource rather than a linked server but I had issues there too) the SP works fine locally, however when I run it remotely, I was just getting error 7302 "can not create instance of provider" then after doing some searching I enabled "allow in process" and "Dynamic Parameter" in the provider settings, and now I'm getting:

> *Msg 7399...
>
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
>   server "JOBDETAILS" reported an error. The provider did not give any
>   information about the error.
>
>   Msg 7303...
>
>   Cannot initialize the data
>   source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked
>   server "JOBDETAILS".*

I looked through event viewer on both the local and remote servers and the local was logging a Com applications permissions issue when I tried to execute from remote using Windows Credentials(the end result will be running with SQL creds but I also tried Windows for troubleshooting purposes) so I corrected the permissions issue but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own stupidity, went back through everything this morning, and realized I had pointed the linked server to a mapped drive.